# How to use percent in calculated column over another calculated column

Tags: calculated-column

I want to create a calculated column which will calculate percentage over another calculated column. E.g.:

I have three columns: ColA, ColB (=ColA-12%), ColC(=ColB-10%).

The problem is, that ColC is not calculated as I wish. I suppose, that it is because it uses another calculated colum.

In the real environment the formulas are more complicated over more columns.

Is there any option how to hack this?

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you replace ColB in ColC formula wiht ColB formula like `ColC(=(ColA-12%)-10%)`

Comment: I can do this that's true. But I'm trying to find out if there is exists another way. In our case ColB is used in another calculated columns and ColB formula can be changed in time. It means, that i will need to change it in all another columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you replace ColB in ColC formula wiht ColB formula like `ColC(=(ColA-12%)-10%)`

Also, if you need help in calculating percentages.. The Calculate Columns actually use Microsoft Excel based formula's so you can take help from here:
[How to do percentages in Excel](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2011/08/02/how-to-do-percentages-in-excel.aspx)